# Use cell's value to get data from "closed" files without using a macro. Note: INDIRECT only works on open files

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've found this question going back to 2015 with no successful answer. They all end up resorting to a macro.

I'm making an employee timesheet master. Each employee has their own file they fill out. All files are kept in the same folder. The Master spreadsheet uses Define Name of FileList with `=FILES('File List'!$A$2)` to get the full list of employee files in the folder. Note: "FileList" is the Name, "File List" is the Tab, and A2 contains the manually entered folder path (example `C:\Employee Files\\*.xlsx*`). This forum won't show the * before and after .xlsx. That formula is repeated downward in column A.

On another tab I have the days of the year going downward in column A and employee files going across row 1 so each filename is listed across the top using `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN(),1,,,"File List"))`. I can use `INDIRECT` because it's looking within the same opened master file, and `ADDRESS(COLUMN()` so I can drag the formula to the right instead of down.

Now the tricky part of getting the data from column H from every closed file using the A2 filepath plus the C1 filename plus the H2 cell in each file, like `'C:\Employee Files\[Doe, Jane.xlsx]Sheet1'!$H2`. I could use `=INDIRECT("'"&LEFT('File List'!$A$2,LEN('File List'!$A$2)-7)&"["&C1&"]Entire Year'!$H2")`, but I would have to have over 100 files open for that to work.

Is there a formula or formulas that can take that combined text value and get the data out of each closed file?

Comment: Look into Powerquery --> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-from-a-folder-with-multiple-files-power-query-94b8023c-2e66-4f6b-8c78-6a00041c90e4